# Enable Protocol HTTP2 Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

How to enable HTTP2 Delphi 11 ?
I has been try with code, but not work

```
NetHTTPClient1.ProtocolVersion := 'HTTP_2_0';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
implementation

uses
  System.Net.HttpClient;

procedure DoSomeHTTPThings;
var
  http: THTTPClient;
  httpresponse: IHTTPResponse;
  stringstream: TSTringStream;
begin
  http := THTTPClient.Create;
  stringstream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    http.ProtocolVersion := THTTPProtocolVersion.HTTP_2_0;
    httpresponse := http.Get('http://exampleurl.com', stringstream);
    case httpresponse.Version of
      THTTPProtocolVersion.UNKNOWN_HTTP: ;
      THTTPProtocolVersion.HTTP_1_0: ;
      THTTPProtocolVersion.HTTP_1_1: ;
      THTTPProtocolVersion.HTTP_2_0: ;
    end;
  finally
    stringstream.Free;
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Edit: 2021-09-23 12:23: Updated the code to your question in comment

Comment: how to get protocol version from response ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I check on fiddler why HTTP/1.1 ? https://image.prntscr.com/image/pETAOJS6QpeX2FYEKcQasw.jpg

Comment: I am no expert but I don't know if it is mandatory to answer with the same protocol version the request was sent. Seems like it's not.

Comment: one question again, how to use Asynchronous on nethttpclient ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that, I'm too clueless for that.

Comment: @Blawjack This website is not a forum/chat: create (a) new question(s) that can be answered instead of relying on comments. Strictly speaking `UNKNOWN_HTTP` can mean `HTTP/0.9`.